# Why does this range blow up

Tags: c++, opencv

Why does the following code segment work

```
int sizearray[3] = {3,4,2};
Mat OneM = Mat::ones(3,4,CV_8UC1);  
Mat TwoM = Mat::ones(3,4,CV_8UC1)+1; 
Mat OneTwo3D = Mat::zeros(3,sizearray,CV_8UC1);
Mat OneTwo3DPlaneM;
Range OneTwo3DRanges[] = {Range(1,3),Range(1,4),Range(1,2)};
OneTwo3DPlaneM = OneTwo3D(OneTwo3DRanges);
```

but if I change the ranges to

```
Range OneTwo3DRanges[] = {Range(1,4),Range(1,4),Range(1,2)};
```

it blows up.

In the working one, `OneTwo3DPlaneM` is apparently a 2x3x1 matrix as expected given that the "end" of a `Range` is exclusive (confirmed by looking at the working code/range result `OneTwo3DPlaneM.size.p` which is `[2,3,1]`).  However, just increasing the first range from `Range(1,3)` to `Range(1,4)` causes an error on

```
OneTwo3DPlaneM = OneTwo3D(OneTwo3DRanges);
```

Note, what I'm trying to do, eventually, is assign an image into a slice of a 3d arrray (via `OneM.copyTo(OneTwo3DPlaneM)` I think).  The code above is just a test for that.  So, I just want to create a matrix that references a plane `OneTwo3D` so that, for this test, I can assign the matrices `OneM` to the first plane and, eventually, `TwoM` to the second plane (after I change the third range to point to `OneTwo3D`'s second plane)

Given that I don't have much experience with opencv I assume I'm doing something retarded. Apologies up front.

Comment: yes, the 'end' of a Range is exclusive, just don't expect it to 'clamp' any value you give it to something valid. as you already found out before, 3 is the max legit value in your case.

Comment: if OneTwo3D is created as a 3x4x2 matrix and range(1,4) ==> 1 through 3 then it certainly should be valid and if it isn't, isn't that  a bug?  After all, if I can't do it this way what other way is there?  Is this not what the operator `Mat Mat::operator()(const Range* ranges) const`is for

Comment: as a sidenote, in most situations, it's better to use a Mat(3,4,CV_32FC(2)) instead. much easier to use, and better support for most maths ops.

Comment: `Range OneTwo3DRanges[] = {Range::all(),Range::all(),Range(1,2)};` ALMOST works.   I wrote ALMOST because, according to the debugger, it set the first **13** bytes (elts 0-12, inclusive), w/r to OneTwo3DPlaneM.data, to 1.  It should have only been **12** as OneM, the copy source,  is a 3x4 matrix.  ???   **Also**, I don't know how I would index the second plane in OneTwo3dPlaneM because I would need to specify a range of Range(2,3) to index plane 2 but then, given what @berak wrote, as OneTwo3dPlaneM is a 3x4x2 matrix that should yield an out of bounds error (as the first example did)

Comment: what does `Mat(3,4,CV_32FC(2))` mean and how does that effect indexing?

Comment: can't seem to delete this

Comment: hey, i forgot to ask the most important one: **why** are you doing this ? images in opencv are *not* 3d Mats with seperated planes, but 2d ones with interleaved pixels. (again, it's *not* matlab) your approach seems to go against the current somehow. what problem are you trying to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work  Apparently, copyTo doesn't like assigning from a 2d into a slice of a 3d array.  So, as shown below, I changed the OneM and TwoM from 3x4 matrices to 3x4x1 and then it worked.  I guess then the question is given an image (2d) can I just reshape it to a 3d entity with a singleton 3rd dimension to copyTo happy.  I'm not sure how to do that considering that reshape only works on 2d arrays.

```
int sizearray1[3] = {3,4,1};
int sizearray[3] = {3,4,2};
//      Mat OneM = Mat::ones(3,4,CV_8UC1);  
Mat OneM = Mat::ones(3,sizearray1,CV_8UC1);  
//      Mat TwoM = Mat::ones(3,4,CV_8UC1)+1;  
Mat TwoM = Mat::ones(3,sizearray1,CV_8UC1)+1;  
Mat OneTwo3D = Mat::zeros(3,sizearray,CV_8UC1);
Mat OneTwo3DPlaneM;
Range OneTwo3DRanges[] = {Range::all(),Range::all(),Range(0,1)};
OneTwo3DPlaneM = OneTwo3D(OneTwo3DRanges);
OneM.copyTo(OneTwo3DPlaneM);
OneTwo3DRanges[2] = Range(1,2);
OneTwo3DPlaneM = OneTwo3D(OneTwo3DRanges);
TwoM.copyTo(OneTwo3DPlaneM);
```